# No gradients provided for any variable, Tensorflow Linear Regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm currently learning how to use Tensorflow and I'm having some issues with this code for a Linear Regression aplication.

Here is the full error description:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["", ""] and loss Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float64).

I've been seeing similar issues reported on this topic and appears to be related to data format conflicts, I'll be thankful if you could give some ideas or knowlegde about the reasson for this error to happen.

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 200
x_points = []
y_points = []
a = 0.22
b = 0.78

for i in range(num_points):
    x = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.5)
    y = a*x + b + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1)
    x_points.append([x])
    y_points.append([y])

plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'o', label='Input Data')
plt.title('Linear Regression')
#plt.legend()
#plt.show()

A = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
Y = tf.add(tf.multiply(A, x_points), B)

cost_function = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(np.array(y) - np.array(y_points)))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
linear_reg = optimizer.minimize(cost_function)
model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(model)
    for step in range(0, 21):
        sess.run(linear_reg)
        if (step % 5) == 0:
            plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'o', label='step = {}'.format(step))
            plt.plot(x_points, sess.run(A)*x_points + sess.run(B))
            plt.legend()
            plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example of your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_points = 200
a = 0.22
b = 0.78
# No need to create everything in a loop, np.random.normal takes a size parameter
x_points = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.5, 200)
y_points = a*x_points + b + np.random.normal(0.0, 0.1, 200)
plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'o', label='Input Data')
plt.title('Linear Regression')

A = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
B = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
Y = tf.add(tf.multiply(A, x_points), B)

# Always see whether the API you are using provides you with the implementation you need. It is more stable, and it will save you a lot of trouble with debugging like right now
cost_function = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y, y_points)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
linear_reg = optimizer.minimize(cost_function)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for step in range(0, 21):
        sess.run(linear_reg)
        if (step % 5) == 0:
            plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'o', label='step ={}'.format(step))
            plt.plot(x_points, sess.run(A)*x_points + sess.run(B))
            plt.legend()
            plt.show()
```